# Where to install manual builds on OSX

Tags: macos, command-line, installation, macports

I have macports installed and it's using the default `/opt/local` location. There are a few packages not in macports and some I tools I wrote that I put in `~/bin`. I found myself needing to use these tools by multiple users on my machine and I don't want to have to copy the same binaries over to each user directory.

`/opt` is a typical suggestion for third-party software and that's why macports uses `/opt/local`. However, it doesn't seem like a good idea to put non-macports packages in `/opt/local`. `/usr` is also commonly suggested but I should probably stay away from that for the same reason macports decided not to use it.

It seems that macports exists entirely in `/opt/local`, so I am inclined to create a new directory in `/opt`, like `/opt/somename`, and mimic the structure to have `/opt/somename/lib` `/opt/somename/bin` etc...

Perhaps I'm a bit anal, but I can't come up with a name for this directory that makes sense. `/opt/local` would have been appropriate, and I wish macports had used `/opt/macports` instead. But I'd rather use as much default config as possible so I don't want to change macport's default directory.

So my question is two parts:

1. What would you call your custom-package directory in `/opt`
2. If you disagree with putting the stuff in `/opt/somname` or anything else in my strategy above, then would you suggest a reasonable, fairly isolated alternative.

I'm really interested in how people have tackled this in their own environments, and I'm surprised I haven't been able to find any info on this. Also, I realize one option is to just create my own port, but I would like to specifically address the two questions above.

Comment: `/usr/local` is perfectly fine to use, at least it's not occupied by default in any OS X installation. Only Homebrew uses it.

Comment: That's also part of the problem I have. I'm looking for a location where I can be sure *nothing* will use that location except for me, but doesn't seem very arbitrary like putting something in `/`. I figure this may seem like a contrived example, but I have seen people with both homebrew and macports, what would you do in that case?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're placing too much emphasis on your directory not being "arbitrary". On the mac, even `/opt` is *arbitrary*, as it's not an integral part of the OS, and there is no `/opt` directory until you create one (or macports does). Once you accept that, your new directory is just a name and some permissions, and there's nothing special about the name.

Fink uses `/sw`. On the one hand, this might be even more "arbitrary" than `/opt`, as I've never noticed it on any of the linuxes I've played with. On the other hand, all of my macs have a `/sw` dir with a bunch of binaries (somewhere) in there – because I use fink – so you could go ahead and use that if you really want to use a name somebody else has used before (assuming you're not using fink yourself). =)

But really, any name will do. It really, really doesn't matter. If your main criterion is using a directory unlikely to be used by anything else, invent the name yourself.